# How to presist some header among all ApiGateway WS session transactions

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, aws-api-gateway

Using ApiGateway websockets, client initiates connection through AWS ApiGateway with authorization header, ApiGateway passes that header from it's context as header to the server endpoint. I want to get this specific header when client invokes $disconnect route upon exiting the connection. is there a way to tell ApiGateway to keep that header along the connection lifetime?